# How to add an Outlook Add-In Button to the main Mail Overview

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to create an Outlook Add-In that will forward the selected mail message as an attachment when the button is pressed. Preferably this will work both for the Outlook Client, and Outlook Web Access. To do this, I need to add a button to the main UI in Outlook which shows the list of messages.

However, within the new Add-In format, I don't see an ExtensionPoint for Outlook that allows adding a button to the main mail UI.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint#extension-points-for-word-excel-powerpoint-and-onenote-add-in-commands

There are options for the MessageRead pane or the MessageCompose pane, but I don't see anything for the general overview.

However, [the following New Feature complains that multiple mail items can't be selected with the add-in syntax](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/11080962-allow-outlook-add-in-commands-to-be-used-on-select), which seems to imply that a single mail item can be selected. If a single mail item can be selected, then that implies that there is a way to add a button to the overview mail page since that's the only place mail can be selected.

This makes me think it is possible to do this, but I'm not sure how.

Can someone please point me to how this might be done?

NOTE: I am NOT trying to create a COM plugin. That is the old format and I've noticed they're increasingly less reliable in Outlook 2016. I am trying to use the new format.

Answer (score 2):

The MessageReadCommandSurface and MessageComposeCommandSurface extension points for Outlook applies to both the main Outlook window (the Explorer) and the item (Inspector) windows.  The Explorer Ribbon buttons activate when an email is selected, so the buttons interact on the selected email.  So you don't have to do anything if you've already defined those extension points.

Comment: This appears to only happen if you have the Read Panel open. If you have that disabled these buttons don't show on the main UI :-(. I guess that will have to do, but not really what I was looking for.